# Laravel Two Column Table

Tags: laravel

I have database like this

ProductTable

```
| id | name      |
| 1  | Product 1 |
```

MachineTable

```
| id | name      |
| 1  | Machine 1 |
| 2  | Machine 2 |
```

ParamsTable

```
| Product_id | Machine_id | Keys   | Value |
|     1      |      1     | Zone 1 |  10   |
|     1      |      2     | Zone 1 |  20   |
|     1      |      2     | Zone 2 |  20   |
```

What i want on the view like this when i find by product_id on ParamsTable:

```
| Keys       | Machine 1  | Machine 2   |
| Zone 1     |     10     |     20      |
| Zone 2     |      -     |     20      |
```

This is my controller

```
public function show(Product $product){
  $data = ParameterSetting::with('product', 'machine')->where('product_id', $product->id)->get();

  return view('production.parameter.view', [
    'machines' => $data->unique('machine.name')->pluck('machine.name'),
    'params' => $data->unique('keys')->pluck('keys'),
    'data' => $data,
  ]);
}
```

But I don't know what is the best way to do. 
What kind of relatiation eloquent should be used and how to loop it.  Thanks Ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are looking for a relationship. you just have to rearrange the data in the form you want and pass it into your view. Here's an example:

```
// rearrange data into $result array
$result = [];
foreach($data as $param){
  $result[$param->keys][$param->machine->name] = $param->value;
}

// pass the new array into the view
return view('production.parameter.view', [
    'machines' => $data->unique('machine.name')->pluck('machine.name'),
    'params' => $data->unique('keys')->pluck('keys'),
    'data' => $data,
    'result' => result
  ]);
```

Which will create this array

```
// $result content
[
  'Zone 1' => [
    'Machine 1' => 10,
    'Machine 2' => 20,
  ],
  'Zone 2' => [
    'Machine 2' => 20
  ]
]
```

so in your view you can loop through it to populate your table

```
@foreach($result as $keys => $values)
  <tr>
    <td> {{ $keys }} </td>
    @foreach($machines as $machineName)
      <td> {{$values[$machineName] ?? '-' }} </td>
    @endforeach
  </tr>
@endforeach
```